# Java Socket not sending message to the Client & The Server

Tags: java, sockets, message, send, serversocket

My Socket isn't sending the messages to the server or back to the client..., IDK Why but I can connect to the server....

I tried to fix this but I cant, Every possible way didn't work for me.
So I hope some people on here may can help me.

Thanks for reading.., Here is the Server:

```
package test;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

import ADG.luxemita.LuxEmita;

public class serverHostTest{

static Socket socket;
static DataInputStream in;
static ServerSocket serverSocket;
//static InputStreamReader isr;
static BufferedReader br;
//static BufferedReader stdBr;
//static InputStream is;
static DataOutputStream out;
//static OutputStreamWriter osw;
static BufferedWriter bw;
//static OutputStream os;
static PrintWriter stdOut;

public serverHostTest(String[] args) throws Exception{
    int port = Integer.parseInt(args[2]);

    LuxEmita.luxLogger.logInfo("Starting Server....");
    serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
    LuxEmita.luxLogger.logInfo("Started Server....");
    socket = serverSocket.accept();
    LuxEmita.luxLogger.logInfo("Intialized Socket....");
    out = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
    out.writeUTF("Server Started Successfully!, Some more data...");

    //SetupEvent.initInstance();

    /*out = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());         
    os = socket.getOutputStream();
    osw = new OutputStreamWriter(os);
    bw = new BufferedWriter(osw);
    stdOut = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);

    in = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());      
    is = socket.getInputStream();
    isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
    br = new BufferedReader(isr);   
    stdBr = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));        
    in2 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));*/

    stdOut = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
    br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));

    if(serverHostTest.serverSocket != null && socket != null){
        new Timer().schedule(new TimerTask() {
            public void run(){
                try {
                    if(br.readLine() != null){
                        String test = br.readLine();
                        System.out.println("Received MSG: " + test);
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }, 1, 1);
    }
}

public static void say(String[] args) throws Exception {
    stdOut.write(args[2]);
    stdOut.flush();
    System.out.println("Message sent to the client is " + args[2]);
}

}
```

Comment: Don't use multiple stream/readers/writers on the same socket. Use the same pair for the life of the socket. Otherwise the buffered ones steal data from the unbuffered ones.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps your issue has something to do with:

```
            try {
                if(br.readLine() != null){
                    String test = br.readLine();
                    System.out.println("Received MSG: " + test);
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Notice how you are reading twice. Store the first `br.readLine()` in a `String` variable and then use that variable instead of reading again.